# How do I download various types of files(images, videos , texts) from Firebase and display them

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am trying to make an app where I need to retrieve data from firebase which can be anything(images, videos , texts) and display them. After searching and through guidance I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26245139/how-to-create-recyclerview-with-multiple-view-type) link, but it doesnt show me how do I download  **all the files** and even how do I get the [getItemViewType()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/RecyclerView.Adapter.html#getItemViewType(int)) to place it in a recycler view.

This is the adapter

```
public class MultiViewTypeAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter {

private ArrayList<Model>dataSet;
Context mContext;
int total_types;
MediaPlayer mPlayer;
private boolean fabStateVolume = false;

public static class TextTypeViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView txtType;
    CardView cardView;

    public TextTypeViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        this.txtType = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.type);
        this.cardView = (CardView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
    }
}

public static class ImageTypeViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView txtType;
    ImageView image;

    public ImageTypeViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        this.txtType = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.type);
        this.image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.background);
    }
}

public static class VideoTypeViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

    TextView txtType;
    VideoView video;

    public VideoTypeViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        this.txtType = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.type);
        this.video = (VideoView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.videoView2);
    }
}

public MultiViewTypeAdapter(ArrayList<Model>data, Context context) {
    this.dataSet = data;
    this.mContext = context;
    total_types = dataSet.size();
}

@Override
public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

    View view;
    switch (viewType) {
        case Model.TEXT_TYPE:
            view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.text_type, parent, false);
            return new TextTypeViewHolder(view);
        case Model.IMAGE_TYPE:
            view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.image_type, parent, false);
            return new ImageTypeViewHolder(view);
        case Model.VIDEO_TYPE:
            view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.video_type, parent, false);
            return new VideoTypeViewHolder(view);
    }
    return null;
}

@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {

    switch (dataSet.get(position).type) {
        case 0:
            return Model.TEXT_TYPE;
        case 1:
            return Model.IMAGE_TYPE;
        case 2:
            return Model.VIDEO_TYPE;
        default:
            return -1;
    }
}

@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, final int listPosition) {

    Model object = dataSet.get(listPosition);
    if (object != null) {
        switch (object.type) {
            case Model.TEXT_TYPE:
                ((TextTypeViewHolder) holder).txtType.setText(object.text);

                break;
            case Model.IMAGE_TYPE:
                ((ImageTypeViewHolder) holder).txtType.setText(object.text);
                ((ImageTypeViewHolder) holder).image.setImageResource(object.data);
                break;
            case Model.VIDEO_TYPE:


                break;
        }
    }
}

@Override
public int getItemCount() {
    return dataSet.size();
}
}
```

This is the model class

```
public class Model {

public static final int TEXT_TYPE=0;
public static final int IMAGE_TYPE=1;
public static final int VIDEO_TYPE=2;

public int type;
public int data;
public String text;

public Model(int type, String text, int data)
{
    this.type=type;
    this.data=data;
    this.text=text;
}
}
```

Comment: provide what have you done so far.

Comment: @Ashish I am having trouble downloading all the files from firebase and setting the correct file type(AUDIO_TYPE , VIDEO_TYPE). Could you please help me

Comment: Also the person who downvoted, can you give a link where this question is answered. It would be of great help. Thank You

Comment: You are going in the wrong direction here. You should be using [Storage](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage) to store that kind of data and the Firebase Realtime Database or Firestore for textual content.

Comment: @Jay That is what.im doing ,All my data is stored in firebase storage

Comment: So what's the issue? If your files are stored in storage, they will maintain their extension (.jpg, .txt etc). You would keep a reference (the path) to those images in Firebase Realtime Database or Firestore and then download them.

Answer (score 1):

They are missing importants information.

Do you use firestore or database real-time ?

If you use firestore and need to get data from document use this code :

```
DocumentReference docRef = db.collection("cities").document("SF");
docRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
    @Override
    public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
        if (task.isSuccessful()) {
            DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
            if (document.exists()) {
                Log.d(TAG, "DocumentSnapshot data: " + document.getData());
            } else {
                Log.d(TAG, "No such document");
            }
        } else {
            Log.d(TAG, "get failed with ", task.getException());
        }
    }
});
```

I you need to get all the documents from a collection in firestore use this :

```
db.collection("cities")
        .get()
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                        Log.d(TAG, document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                }
            }
        });
```

if your use realtime your need this :

```
ValueEventListener postListener = new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        // Get Post object and use the values to update the UI
        Post post = dataSnapshot.getValue(Post.class);
        // ...
    }
```

For the getItemViewType() in your link this a method create for the sample. He define a view holder for odd and even item.

Comment: While answers are appreciated, this doesn't address the question of *retrieve data from firebase which can be anything(images, videos , texts) and display them*. The Firebase Realtime Database and Firestore are not appropriate for storing that kind of data.